# Having SonarQube Ignore Abstract classes?

Tags: java, sonarqube

Is there a way to have SonarQube's analysis ignore abstract classes? Setting up SonarQube for some Legacy code and I'd really like to avoid going through and typing a specific exclusion for each and every abstract class in the project. Is there anyway to do this neatly?

Comment: If there isn't I was thinking it might be possible to write a python script that would scan the legacy software, and store the names of all Abstract classes. Then merely copy and paste that list into the Sonar Exclusion.

Comment: What is the underlying purpose of ignoring abstract classes ? I can't think of a good reason why you want to avoid issues on such classes ?

Comment: There are a lot of abstract classes that have no implementation other than when they are returned from a DAO object. Any Unit tests written do not cover their lines and therefore there are portions of our project that bring down our Code Coverage with no way to test the abstract classes. Sonar is adding these to our Report and because of their size(50 to 70 setters and getters per class) they are appearing as huge grey boxes and bringing down our coverage %.

Answer (score 0):

If the classes have a package or naming convention in common, you should be able to [set up an exclusion pattern](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus) for them.

Comment: Sadly they do not. If only that were the case I would have gone down that route.